# Mediaelement.js, html5 and flash video: getting height and width to be 100%

Tags: video, html5-video, mediaelement.js

I want to make a video appear at 100% width and 100% height of the viewport. I'm using Mediaelement.js for the video, which ensures native playing in Chrome, Safari and IE9, and a Flash fallback for Firefox and IE8.

Problem is, in native playback or Flash playback the video doesn't go all the way to 100% height of the containing div. It leaves spacing at the top and bottom, to account for the aspect ratio of the video.

Check out an example at http://badlands777.com/test

Is is possible to make a video completely fill out the containing div? In the native  tag as well as the Flash fallback player?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a style attribute to your video tag, with height and width set to 100%.

```
<video style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
```

mediaelement.js will transfer the values to the appropriate parts in the output HTML.